# Deleting 2 items from Programs: Dell laptop, Windows 10 after startup message

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, touchpad, dell-latitude

Everytime I startup my laptop, I get this popup:

> Deleting 2 items from Programs

and it also says:

> TouchPad Options 1000 bytes

I went to CCleaner and, in Tools-> Startup, I stopped the program Apoint, from Alps Electric Co, which is in C:\Program Files\DellTPad because I think it's the driver or related to it, but nothing changed.

My PC is a DELL Latitude E5470.

Comment: Can you try going through your startup items using MSCONFIG and uncheck items you are not familiar with from the startup tab?

Comment: just checked and it's the same program I already disabled: Alps Pointing-device Driver. Then, I also have "delayed launcher" and "Plcon startup utility", both from Intel Corportation, that are enabled and I'm not sure what they are but I don't think they are related, I think they have something to do with the security of the system.